# React component does not paint directly after returning JSX

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that captures a frame from a video stream, then runs an AI model on the captured image and then shows some predictions.

The model predictions are slow. It takes a few seconds for the model to analyze the predictions. In the mean time I want the UI to reflect that the software is busy analyzing, so I introduced a state variable that indicates this.

Roughly speaking, here is what I do in an effect hook:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (captured && !analyzing && !results) {
    setAnalyzing(true)
    model.detect().then((predictions) => {
      setAnalyzing(false)
      setResults(predictions)
    })
  }
}, [ captured, analyzing, results ])
```

What I am seeing however, is that the screen updates only *after* the model is finished.

My component is a functional component, ending with a return statement that returns JSX.
So I added a console.info call just before the return statement:

```js
  // ...
  console.info('analyzing', analyzing)
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Analyzing: {analyzing ? 'true' : 'false'}</p>
      // ... 
    </div>
  )
```

Here is the weird thing: I see this message appear in the console *directly* after the analysis starts... But still the screen does not actually update. It shows 'Analyzing: false'. Then, only when the model is ready, the screen updates, but because by that time `analyzing` is `false` again, I never actually see the screen change to that state. The model takes seconds to do the analysis, so I have a time window of a few seconds in which I can see the console message staring at me saying `analyzing true`, while at the same time I see in the HTML `Analyzing: false`.

I also get this warning in the console:

```
[Violation] 'message' handler took 383ms
```

which I think might be related.

I left a lot of detail out because I don't think it is relevant atm. But just for clarity let me show a snippet of logging from my actual app:

```
right before the call, analysing= false
index.js:104 =======================================
index.js:105 Setting analyzing to true
index.js:106 about to call model.detect
index.js:107 call me crazy, but I expect the screen to update NOW
index.js:108   and not only after the promise from model.detect resolves...
index.js:109 =======================================
index.js:112 right after the call, analysing= false
react-dom.development.js:174 [Violation] 'message' handler took 383ms
index.js:128 rendering dialog open true streaming true captured true analysing true results null
index.js:151 returning JSX, analysing= true
i18next.js:22 i18next::translator: missingKey en translations Analysing.... Analysing....
i18next.js:22 i18next::translator: missingKey en translations OK OK
scheduler.development.js:154 [Violation] 'message' handler took 392ms
index.js:116 ANALYSIS COMPLETE arguments Arguments [callee: (...), Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ]
```

If you look at the last few lines, the message `returning JSX` is the one right before the return statement of the functional component. The message `ANALYSIS COMPLETE` is logged seconds later, when the model predictions are returned. In those seconds, I see this message saying `analyzing= true`, but I don't see that reflected in the page. In the HTML itself, it does not update at all until *after* the `ANALYSIS COMPLETE` message is printed seconds later.

So, my questions:

What can cause React to delay updating the HTML? How can I debug this to find out?
Should I move the model interpretation to a web worker to prevent freezing the screen?
Are there any known ways to prevent the freezing and make sure my update happens first?

One thing I tried is to use `setTimeout` and call `model.detect` only after the screen was updated and that does do the trick, but I feel it is a dirty hack... Or is that actually a good way to solve it?
Any pointers to docs I could read about this would be helpful. Not looking for a definitive answer but for hints / suggestions on how to investigate the source of the freezing.

Comment: try async await with model. It will work. Use only dependency of analyzing. check the `if(!analyzing){ // your code}`

Comment: Isn't `async` ... `await` just syntax suger for `Promise` ... `then`? If you look at the code you see that after the call to `model.detect` the handling of the results happen in `then`. Changing to `async` ... `await` wouldn't actually change anything afaik.

Comment: Also, the console.log statement shows that my JSX has already returned with `analyzing=true` seconds before the `model.detect` call completes. So my code already did it's work. It handed the JSX to React already... It's just that the HTML is not actually updating, probably because the page is frozen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `model.detect()` is probably blocking the main thread, you could confirm by checking if you app responds to events while the detection is happening.

This is probably the solution:

> Should I move the model interpretation to a web worker to prevent freezing the screen?

Comment: Yes you are right. No events were happening. Like link hover did nothing until after detection finished. Moved to code to a web worker and it solves it. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: mind elaborate what is "move xxx to a web worker"?